# How can I capture the 720p fps60 video?

Tags: pi-3b+

I tried to use below command to capture the video, but output video fps only 25:

```
raspivid -rot 180 -t 10000 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 60 -b 1200000 -p 0,0,1280,720 -o test.h264
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: what is the frame rate of the video that you are trying to capture?

Answer (score 4):

You are recording raw h264 which does not contain any timestamp information. What are you using to play back the recording - its probably just reporting a default fps value. You can calculate the approximate fps based on the number of frames and the duration (seconds) of the recording.

From a Raspberry Pi Engineer:

> You are recording at 30fps, but a raw H264 elementary stream (what's in test.h264) has no timestamp information. MP4Box is assuming 25fps in the absence of any other information.
>   The fact that you recorded for 10seconds and got 295 frames gives you 29.5fps. (It takes a few 100ms to get going at the start).
>
> There is a mode for raspivid where it will write out all the timestamps to a second file, and mkvmerge can use that when putting the H264 stream into the container.

```
raspivid -w 1280 -h 1024 -fps 30 -t 10000 -o test.h264 -pts timestamps.txt
mkvmerge -o bb.mkv --timecodes 0:timestamps.txt test.h264
```

> That does produce an mkv file instead of mp4, but almost all players support mkv as well.
>
> Alternatively you can just add "-fps 30" to your MP4Box line and it'll assume the H264 ES is at 30fps.
>   (Location within the command may be important. It'll either be "MP4Box -fps 30 -add ...", or "MP4Box -add test.h264 -fps 30 ...")

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=195228#p1221819

Answer (score 3):

Try running `raspivid` with one of the modes listed here under `--mode, -md` https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md

In those two tables you can also see that 60fps is only supported for 640x480 video (Version 1 camera) or 1280x720 (Version 2).

[image: RPi Camera Modes]